Sync 2 Git repos
I cloned a month ago a Github public repo directly into a new private Azure DevOps repo, by using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops , since we are implementing new software which is hosted in a Github public repo. The reason for saving the code also in ADO is since we have few parameter files that we need to modify.
After this original clone directly from GitHub to ADO, I cloned locally on my laptop and created a new branch for DEV based on main, by adding one commit that contain 4 yaml files : 2 new parameter files and 2 updated files. Then pushed DEV branch to ADO.
git clone https://OrgName@dev.azure.com//Project/_git/RepoName 
git switch main
git checkout -b DEV
#add 2 new yaml files and update 2 files
Git add .
Git commit -m “Added and Updated Config files”
Git remote add github https://github.com/Software/Project.git
git push -u origin DEV

In the meantime in Github there were 4 additional commits on the main. I need to update both the main and DEV branches in ADO based on Github main branch changes, now and in future for any further Github new commits.
I am fairly new to Git but reviewed the documentation in depth. My question is can you please check following steps and let me know if make sense to you, or you see an issue.
git fetch github 
git switch main 
git rebase github/main
git push -u origin main
git switch DEV
git rebase github/main
git push -u origin DEV


It's not clear what the question is...?

I think your commands are correct, where is the question? or is the question is asking for feedback or review your commands?

yes, my question is if you can pls review my commands, if make sense to you or you see an issue.

The git rebase command applies the changes from the github/main branch onto your current branch. It doesn’t remove any files that are present in your current branch (DevOps) but not in the github/main branch. Hence, if you have a file in DevOps repo, while not in Github repo, the file will remain in DevOps repo which means different files between DevOps and Github.
In addition, with git rebase command, it could have conflicts, you could need to resolve the conflicts before you push to DevOps.
# Edit the files to resolve the conflicts, then
git add <resolved-file>
git rebase --continue

Since you are tracking two repos (DevOps and Github), it could be more clear if you git clone two repos separately in local, copy & paste content from github repo folder to DevOps repo folder, then push to remote DevOps. It's recommended to do in this way.
Edit:
To keep the commit SHA, user info and times, you can use git reset command instead. This command will reset your origin repository to match the github repository exactly, removing any files that exist in origin but not in github.
# Fetch the latest changes from github
git fetch github

# Switch to the main branch
git switch main

# Reset the local main branch to match the github main branch
git reset --hard github/main

# Force push to origin. This will overwrite all changes on origin/main with github/main
git push -f origin main


You can do same for DEV branch, and then push the 4 yaml files : 2 new parameter files and 2 updated files to DEV branch. So that DEV branch will have the extra files again main branch as you did in first git commands.
git switch DEV
#add 2 new yaml files and update 2 files
Git add .
Git commit -m “Added and Updated Config files”
git push -u origin DEV

Note: If you are sure the DevOps repo has no extra file with Github, you can use git rebase command as you did before.

Thank you a lot @wade-zhou-msft for your reply. I did not understand the last part "it could be more clear if you git clone two repos separately in local, copy&paste content from github repo folder to DevOps repo folder, then push to remote DevOps. It's recommended to do in this way." Do you mean to check for every of the missing commits from Github source the changes and then copy/paste modified or new files and delete from destination the deleted files from source. and this manually? But I would like to see the same commit SHA, users and times on ADO destination copy as in Github source.

Yes, you can remove devops file folder content, and copy github repo folder simply, and then push to devops repo. But if you would like to keep the info from github source, and ensure devops repo same as github repo(remove files only in devops), you can use git reset command instead. I will update the answer with details. Please check.

Thank you a lot @wade-zhou-msft for your reply. I understand up to
git push -f origin main
/* but when I reset local DEV branch to match the github main branch I lose the previous commit with the 4 files and I have to save the files separately in another saved branch, correct? /
git switch DEV
git reset --hard github/main
#add 2 new yaml files and update 2 files
git add .
git commit -m “Added and Updated Config files”
/ __then fix if conflicts appear after I reset DEV (same as github/main) and apply the new files changes __  */
git push -u origin DEV

As per your 1st part commands, the 4 files are only pushed to DEV branch(not main). Yes,  git reset will keep exactly same with github repo, it will remove them in DEV. That's why i suggested you can push 4 files after reset to DEV. If you ensure never editing from DevOps repo, you can still use git rebase, it won't remove the 4 files. Please check the Note above.

Thank you a lot @wade-zhou-msft for your reply. is there an advantage to modify code to "merge" instead of "rebase" like I showed in original post : git fetch github   git switch main   git merge github/main   git push -u origin main   git switch DEV
git __merge__ github/main
git push -u origin DEV`

git merge takes all the changes in one branch and merges them into another branch in one commit. If you would like better project history(have github info), you should use git rebase. You can check the link for the difference between merge and rebase.
